# How to get value post array in codeigniter?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

How to get value post array in codeigniter?
I have problem when I get value post array and echo the value. How to show post value when submit?
here the error message:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Uninitialized string offset: 0

Filename: controllers/blablabla
```

view html:

```
<?php $i=0; foreach ($doc as $row) { ?>
<label>
<input name="size[<?php echo $i; ?>]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row['doc']; ?>">&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $row['doc']; ?>
</label>
<?php $i++; } ?>
```

controller :

```
$size = $this->input->post('size');
for ($i=0; $i<count($doc); $i++) 
{
   echo $size[$i];
}
```

Comment: Do this $arr = $this->input->post(); print_r($arr); and check if you are getting, and yes, values will come which are checked only

Comment: @rahul_m I do that you suggested, just show white screen.

Comment: Have you kept die(); exit; ? after print_r and obvious it will come after posting form not as direct if you are using same function for loading form and posting form

Comment: @rahul_m : yes I do, here my code $size   = $this->input->post('size');
    print_r($size);
    die(); the result still white screen.

Comment: No I didn't suggested this, check my comment or copy paste it. Your posted code is wrong

Comment: @rahul_m : Ok, I do that and get all value post except value size, can you tell me why? I have edit checkbox to checked and the result still empty.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141933/discussion-between-rahul-m-and-silvia-zulinka).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the way name of checkbox written as follows,

```
<?php foreach ($doc as $row) { ?>
<label>
  <input name="size[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row['doc']; ?
  >">&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $row['doc']; ?>
</label>
<?php } ?>
```

And in post method,

```
$size_arr = $this->input->post('size');
foreach($size_arr as $v){
  echo $v;
}
```

if for some reason it is not working then check with,

```
$size_arr = $_POST['size'];
foreach($size_arr as $v){
  echo $v;
}
```

**EDIT**

One more alternative,

```
$arr = $this->input->post();
$size_arr = $arr['size'];
foreach($size_arr as $v){
  echo $v;
}
```

Core version,

```
$arr = $_POST;
$size_arr = $arr['size'];
foreach($size_arr as $v){
  echo $v;
}
```

Comment: thats still not working, I got this message A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: check my edit section, if still not working, print_r($arr) and post here, I will look into it

Comment: I got more error message A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: size

Comment: It means, you are not getting size input values, can you show me $arr values

Comment: you sure, form's attribute method is post ?

Comment: yes, I sure.. when I do that you suggested $arr = $this->input->post(); print_r($arr); all post show value except size

Comment: here the result when I do  $arr = $this->input->post(); print_r($arr);  https://ibb.co/f5ety5

Comment: check this [link](http://codepad.org/V9Dr4BuM), create new file and check the output. you will get it

Comment: I found the problem, the problem is because name post is size, I rename size to other like sizea thats working, I dont know why name size is problem ?

Answer (score 2):

Your html form code should be like below.

```
<input name="size[<?php echo $i; ?>]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row['doc']; ?>">
```

Inside controller your code should be like below.

```
$size = $this->input->post('size');
foreach($size as $sa)  
{
   echo $sa;
}
```

Comment: Wykar : thats not working, I got error message A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Answer (score 2):

No need to use $i in checkbox name in view file just take an array

View file

```
<?php foreach ($doc as $row) { ?>
<label>
<input name="size[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row['doc']; ?>">&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $row['doc']; ?>
</label>
<?php  } ?>
```

Controller

```
$countsize = count($this->input->post('size'));
for ($i=0; $i<$countsize ; $i++) 
{
   echo $this->input->post('size')[$i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me

In View file

```
<div id="area_input">
  <div id="inputan" class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="size[]" placeholder="ukuran">
    </div>  
    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="size[]" placeholder="ukuran">
    </div>   
    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="size[]" placeholder="ukuran">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="size[]" placeholder="ukuran">
    </div>            
  </div>  
</div>
```

you can repeat input as needed.

in Controller file

```
$data = array(
            'size' => $this->input->post('size'),
        );
```

You can check stucture of array using print_r($data), or print 'em using:

```
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
   foreach ($value as $detail) {
        echo $detail;
        echo "<br>";
    }
}
```